# let X be a Non-negative random variable with E(X) = 1. Show that for any c > 0 then $\int_{0}^{c} ( 1 − \frac{x}{c})dF(x) \geq 1- \frac{1}{c}$

Tags: probability-theory

let X be a Non-negative random variable with E(X) = 1. Show that for any c > 0 then $\int_{0}^{c} ( 1 − \frac{x}{c})dF(x) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{c}$

My attempt:

First I let $\int_{0}^{c} ( 1 − \frac{x}{c})dF(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{c} (1)dF(x)  − \int_{0}^{c}(\frac{x}{c})dF(X)$

Im not sure where to go from here. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The question does not make sense. If you are integrating w.r.t $x$ then LHS does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are correct, I edited the problem, I mixed up the x and put it on the RHS not the LHS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(1-\frac X c)^{-} \geq 0$ Hence $E(1-\frac X c)^{+}=E(1-\frac X c)^{-}+E(1-\frac X c) \geq E(1-\frac X c) =1-\frac 1  c$. This equivalent to the given ineuality.

Comment: Sorry if I am not seeing it but I have a followup question from your answer. 
how do you relate the integral above to the expected values, wouldnt you need the bound of the integral to be $\int_{0}^{\infty}$

Comment: $E(1-\frac X c)^{+}=\int_0^{\infty} (1-\frac x c)^{+} dF(x)$ and $(1-\frac x c)^{+}=0$ for $x >c$.

Comment: Ah that make sense, Thank you!